# Creating a set of letters written in different fonts

Tags: macos, python-2.7, neural-network, pybrain

I want to train my pyBrain network to recognise digits. They should be written in 16x16 bmp files. Since drawing manually 10 digits is not enough for machine to learn, how is it possible to generate a lot (20-40 each) of single digit files using many fonts (preferably already installed on computer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used pillow, and downloaded some fonts, so I successfully generated many files.
Thank you, community, for help.